# Symmetricds fails to synchronize default value column

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, data-synchronization, symmetricds

Symmetricds server is configured with postgresql 9.4 and client nodes have sqlite3. I recently had to alter a table at the server end and then send the schema to the client with the command `symadmin send-schema --engine <server> --node <node> <table>`

One of the changes in the table was the addition of default value on date field `update_date date DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date`

Since the changes is applied, on symmetric log I am seeing the following error message on the server side now:

`ERROR [<server>] [AcknowledgeService] [qtp1874154700-1322] The outgoing batch <node>-41837 failed. ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "'now'::text)::date"`

Is this error showing up because sqlite3 does not support `'now'::text)::date"` as default value? In such case how can I propagate the changes?

OR

If it is a symmetricds issue that it is not recognizing `'now'::text)::date"` as default value for `update_date` field?

I am suspecting due to this error all the synchronization between client and server is stopping.

Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hope the problem is not in production

you'll need to delete the outgoing batch with the change or just the link between it and the alter table

use the command line then to send the custom native SQL DDL statement to each node from the central node or do it manually connecting remotely to each node

Comment: Thanks @Boris Pavlović but did not fully understand your suggestion. So I need to delete the particular entry from 'sym_outgoing_batch' ... how can delete the link to alter table command. At the end instead of schema you are suggesting to send raw sql ddl instead right?

Comment: delete the row in sym_data_event that links the failing outgoing batch with the sym_data row holding the alter table expression

Answer (score 0):

A batch in error will hold up all other batches in error.  You can ignore the batch in error by setting the status to "IG" on that particular batch.   However this would result in all change captures in the batch to not be applied on the target.

Are you sure the default value applied correctly on **SQLITE**.  Here is an example of a table with a default date value of now.

```
create table forum (id int primary key, some_date date default(date('now')));
```

You can then send the appropriate alters or creates to your clients through the send **sql** feature.

References:

- [Open source send documentation](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_send).
- [Professional send documentation](http://www.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_send).